# Rails: Changing the name of namespaced model to point to correct active record table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ckeditor

I currently have a Rails model in a namespace `Rom::RomUsers`. This model points to an database table called `rom_users`

I was wondering if there is anyway I can edit the model name to `Rom::Users` and have it still point to the database table `rom_users`. This project has the gem `ckeditor` installed and it seems to be using this convention fine. It has a database table called `ckeditor_assets` and here is the model.

```
class Ckeditor::Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Ckeditor::Orm::ActiveRecord::AssetBase
  include Ckeditor::Backend::Paperclip

  rails_admin do
    visible false
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_table_name` method.

```
class Rom::Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "rom_users"
end
```